# Proof by contradiction confusion

Tags: logic, proof-verification

I am having confusions on some basic stuff. Could you help me out, please?

Consider the following statement:

"If A then B or C"

If we apply proof by contradiction method to this statement then we assume the contrary of "B or C" which is "not B and not C". Than if we deduce "B or C" by using "A" then does this count as a proof?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have to prove
$$A\Longrightarrow B $$
The thing you are looking for is: Assume that $A$ is valid and assume for a contradiction that $B$ is invalid. You would then consider
$$A\land \neg B $$
If that yields a contradiction, then the assumption that $B$ is invalid, is incorrect. Hence $A\Longrightarrow B$

Another way is to prove by showing the contrapositive is valid i.e $\neg B\Longrightarrow \neg A$.

In your case we consider:
$$A\Longrightarrow B\lor C $$
Assume for a contradiction that $\neg B\land \neg C$, then it must be true that:
$$A\land\neg B\land\neg C $$

You had suggested a proof by:
$$A\land\neg B\land\neg C\Longrightarrow B\lor C $$
You will no make progress, for we can apply your method indefinitely and arrive at:
$$A\land\neg B\land\neg C\land A\land\neg B\land\neg C\Longrightarrow B\lor C $$
Which is the exact same thing we started with. Stuck in a circle.

The problem is that you are using the validity of the very thing you try to verify as part of your assumption.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still don't get it. What is the contradiction if A∧¬B∧¬C is true?   How about putting it this way:                                                                              Claim: A⟹B∨C
Proof: Assume the contrary so ¬B∧¬C is true. Furthermore A∧¬B∧¬C ⟹ B∨C. Hence a contradiction. QED. Does this count as a proof? Is it really a contradiction? Can I contradict with my contrary assumption? Thank you :)

Comment: Another example:
If $n$ is an even number, then $2n$ is an even number or an odd number.
You would suggest:
If $n$ is even and $2n$ is not even and $2n$ is not odd, then $2n$ is even or $2n$ is odd.

You are talking in circles.

Comment: What we would do is assume for a contradiction that $2n$ is not even and $2n$ is not odd. Then
$n$ is even and $2n$ is not even and $2n$ is not odd. Clearly a contradiction, therefore it must be true that $2n$ is either even or odd.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I have three assumptions n is even (initial assumption) and 2n is not even and 2n is not odd (contrary assumption). Then I am making some logical deductions from these three assumptions and deducing that 2n is even or odd. Now i am in a situation where a statement is true and false which is "2n is even or odd" or "NOT (2n is even or odd)". Is it a contradiction? It shouldn't be right?

Comment: OR even simpler version. Claim: If A then B. Proof: Assume not, assume that "not B" is true. Since A is true and "not B" is true, B is true. Hence contradiction. QED. From what I understand, this is not a proof.

Comment: You assumed $\neg B$ is true, which will make $B$ false. Logically you then arrive at:
$$A\land \neg B\Longrightarrow B $$
and that implication is false, of course. There is no contradiction, everything is exactly as it should be.

Comment: Let's consider something impossible. If Birds can fly, then humans can fly.
Assume that humans can't fly, then:
If birds can fly and humans can't fly, then humans can fly.
There is no contradiction, but your method, if correct, would verify the validity of this statement, but we can all agree that this statement is false: humans can't fly (without aid, that is) and it's therefore the validity of your method that would come into consideration, instead.

Comment: If we look at a possible scenario, instead: If birds can fly (which is true), then humans can't fly (which is also true). Let's prove it.
Assume for a contradiction that humans can fly, then
Birds can fly and humans can fly - a clear contradiction.
Your method would provide us:
If birds can fly and humans can fly, then humans can't fly
You would arrive at correct result with false assumption, that is of no use to anyone.

Comment: I got it now, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Kutay It's no problem. I recommend you take a look at "propositional calculus".

Answer (score 1):

Deducing "B or C" using "A" would be a direct proof - perfectly valid, but it sounds like you're looking specifically for a proof by contradiction.

A proof by contradiction would go like this: assume for contradiction that it is not the case that "if A, then B or C". ("For contradiction" is a phrase that's sometimes used to make it clear that this assumption isn't actually expected to be true.) To say that it isn't the case is to say that there is a counterexample; in other words, a situation where A is true but neither B nor C is. Suppose we're in such a situation. We then prove (by whatever means) a contradiction; usually something like "A and not A". Since this is clearly false, our assumption - that "if A then B or C" was not true - must have been false. Therefore, if A then B or C.

Another variation, which I think would be more straightforward but sort of buries the proof by contradiction, would be to begin by assuming A, and then assume for contradiction that not B and not C. We then (by some means) deduce (for example) not A. Now, by our first assumption, we have both A and not A. This is a contradiction, so our second assumption is false: it must be that B or C. We're still inside the first assumption, though, so we haven't proven that B or C is true in general - just that IF A is true, THEN B or C. Which, conveniently, is exactly what we were hoping for.

There are more options - the option I'd use personally would be proof by contrapositive, which looks a lot like contradiction but isn't technically the same. But that doesn't seem to be what your question was about, so I won't go into that.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, no. If you deduce ‘B or C’ by using A, you have a direct proof. A proof by contradiction would deduce from ‘not B and not C’ an assertion which is both true and false (e.g. $\sqrt 2$ is rational, as there are proofs it's false).

However, note that if the contradicting assertion is that $A$ is false, whereas we've supposed it to be true, it is not really a proof by contradiction, but rather a proof by contrapositive.

Comment: Another possibility is deducing ‘(not A)’ from ‘A and (not B) and (not C)’, which would be an actual proof by contradiction, provided the hypothesis ‘A’ is used (otherwise it would be, as you remark, a proof by contrapositive). A typical case is Saccheri's dismissal of the “obtuse angle hypothesis”: from assuming it, he deduced the “right angle hypothesis”, which contradicts the hypothesis itself.

Comment: @egreg: That's why I began writing ‘In principle’. I mainly wanted to insist on the fact that so  many would-be proofs by contradiction are proofs by contrapositive, really .

Comment: Yes, we see them all the time. `:-(` A prominent example is in many “proofs by contradiction” of the infinitude of primes where instead a *constructive* method is used, so no contradiction at all.

Comment: For this one, it's so much simpler to explain one is going to prove any finite list of prime numbers is incomplete.

Comment: Why this downvote?

Answer (score -1):

The proof by contradiction in this case would be to show an example where "A" is true but neither "B" nor "C" are true.

Comment: It would be a counter-example to the assertion, I'd say.